# htaccess URL executes wrong

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have return the below htaccess rule for actual URL http://apis.jaspee.com/services/srvcRest.php?rqst=getCMS

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ services/srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

but it works as

http://apis.jaspee.com/services/srvcRest.php?rqst=services/getCMS

because of that the page is redirected to page not found page. $1 fetch the value as services/getCMS but I want the $1 should fetch the value as getCMS only.

Comment: can anyone give me the suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its going in root /.htaccess, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/srvcRest\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^services/(.*)$ services/srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

If its going in /services/.htaccess, try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/srvcRest\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ srvcRest.php?rqst=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: tried with both the rule but still page goes to 404 page :(

Comment: what's the exact URL you're testing with? what does your error log report when the 404 occurs? are you wanting an internal redirect (browser address displays original request URL while serving redirected content) or an external redirect (browser address changes to reflect URL of redirected content)?